# How to get a specific column from a custom Adapter

Tags: android, autocomplete, android-view, android-adapter

How can I retrieve a specific attribute of my class from a Custom Adapter? I tried tag, but without no success. Any ideas how could this be accomplish?

I have the following adapter whit the autocomplete:

```
final ArrayList<City> cities = new ArrayList<City>();
final CityAdapter arrayAdapter = new CityAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, cities);
autoCompleteTextViewDropDown.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

My view looks something like this:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Get the data item for this position
    City city = (City) getItem(position);
    // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_city, parent, false);
    }

    // Lookup view for data population
    TextView tvName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
    tvName.setText(city.getName());

    final ImageView tvFavourite = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvFavourite);

    // Populate the data into the template view using the data object
    if(city.favourite==false) tvFavourite.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_star);
    else tvFavourite.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_star_on);
    //IMPORTANT QUANDO PROGRAMAR A DIALOG BOX FAZER AQUI
    tvFavourite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            tvFavourite.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_star_on);
        }
    });


    convertView.setTag(String.valueOf(city.getName()));
    // Return the completed view to render on screen
    return convertView;
}
```

This is my autocomplete:

```
     final AutoCompleteTextView autoCompleteTextViewDropDown;
        autoCompleteTextViewDropDown = findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextViewDropDown);
...
autoCompleteTextViewDropDown.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

Click Listener in MainActivity:

```
autoCompleteTextViewDropDown.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                String Column_id = (String) arg0.getTag();
                coValue.setText(Column_id);
                if (!(autoCompleteTextViewDropDown.getText().toString().equals(""))){
                     autoCompleteTextViewDropDown.setText((String) arg0.getTag());
                }
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        autoCompleteTextViewDropDown.showDropDown();
                    }
                }, 100);
            }
        });
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to do ?

Comment: I want to get the tv.name when i click in one of the autocomplete options. Instead of the City class, wich im unable to use.

Comment: I can't see any AutoCompleteTextView in your code.

Comment: i don't see a click listener other than the one on tvFavourite

Comment: Do u guys have any sugestions?

Comment: @Raghunandan has answered.  i was going to do the same :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set a item click Listener and use position which is the index and get the item that you want.

```
autoCompleteTextViewDropDown.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
public void onItemClick (AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
       City city = (City) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
       String name = city.getName();
}
});
```

Comment: .getName doesnt existe

Comment: @JoãoMarques what does `parent.getItemAtPosition(position)` give you `city`?

Comment: ye, u need to do getClass().getName(), i think let me test

Comment: @JoãoMarques check now the edited one. just cast it.

Comment: Im still retriaving a citys, however im unable to convert it to city.

Comment: Thanks i been trying to do this for 2 days. You the best.

Answer (score 0):

you can  do in this way set tag to the row view in getView of the adapter like this

```
  @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
// Get the data item for this position
City city = (City) getItem(position);
// Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
if (convertView == null) {
    convertView = inflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_city, parent, false);
}

// Lookup view for data population
TextView tvName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
tvName.setText(city.getName());

final ImageView tvFavourite = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvFavourite);

// Populate the data into the template view using the data object
if(city.favourite==false) tvFavourite.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_star);
else tvFavourite.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_star_on);
//IMPORTANT QUANDO PROGRAMAR A DIALOG BOX FAZER AQUI
tvFavourite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        tvFavourite.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_star_on);
    }
});


convertView.setTag(String.valueOf(city.getName()));
// Return the completed view to render on screen
return convertView;
   }
```

and then

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int position, long id) {    
 String columid= (String) arg1.getTag();
```

Comment: However cause im reatrieving a city, the autocomplete stop working, do u have any ideia how could i "force" the auto complete to use only the name?

Comment: u can try this try      autoCompleteTextViewDropDown.setText((String) arg0.getTag().toString());